# Solr export / replication to a database

Tags: solr

My current application has a Solr engine for storing large amounts of data, however I would like to have some of this data copied over to a PostGres database.

Ideally this "replication" should have a delta comparation mechanism for not missing any data coming from Solr.

I can see lots of examples for importing the data from a database into Solr (DataImportHanlder) but not the other way around, I cannot find any DataExportHandler in the Solr Documentation.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Usually Solr is not the repository of the source data, but rather Solr holds a *copy* of the data optimized for searching. What is the source of your Solr data?

Comment: You can usually use the `_version_` field to keep track of the largest value you've seen so far. Store that value and use it as the delta for which documents has been updated since your last fetch.